# Find the maximum value of $2x + 2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the maximum value of $2x + 2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1.$

I'm trying to find the upper bound of the expression, but I'm having trouble on how to start/how to solve the problem. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try? Are you familiar with differentiation?

Comment: if you dont know about derivatives there is  a method using trigonometric substituition

Comment: I would like a answer/hint without calculus, because I didn't learn it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Try to plug $x = cos^{2}(\theta)$ and use some trigonometry to see what can be the maximum value of $sin(A) + cos(A)$.

I hope this helps. If you are stuck, let me know!

Update : Since the OP seems not to follow the hint and work through it, I'll give the complete solution:

Plug in $x = cos^{2}(\theta)$, then we get:

$ 2x + 2\sqrt{x(1-x)} = 2cos^{2}(\theta) + 2 \sqrt{cos^{2}(\theta)(1-cos^{2}(\theta))} = 2cos^{2}(\theta) + 2 \sqrt{cos^{2}(\theta)sin^{2}(\theta)}$ $\mbox{ 
      } $ , using the identity $cos^{2}(\theta) + sin^{2}(\theta) = 1$

$ = 2cos^{2}(\theta) + 2 sin(\theta) cos(\theta) = [1 + cos(2\theta)] + sin(2\theta)$ $\mbox{  }$ (using the identities : $cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2cos^{2}(\theta)$ and $sin( 2\theta) = 2 sin(\theta) cos(\theta)$ )

Now we find maximum of $cos(2\theta) + sin(2\theta)$ :

$cos(2\theta) + sin(2\theta) = \sqrt{2} [1/\sqrt{2} sin(2\theta) + 1/\sqrt{2} cos(2\theta)] = \sqrt{2} [cos(\pi/4) sin(2\theta) + sin(\pi/4) cos(2\theta)] = \sqrt{2}sin( \pi/4 + 2\theta)$

using the identity $sin( A +B) = sin(A)cos(B) + cos(A)sin(B)$

Since maximum value of $sin( \pi/4 + 2\theta) = 1$, $cos(2\theta) + sin(2\theta) \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Thus, $ 2x + 2\sqrt{x(1-x)} \leq 1 + \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Could I get a hint without calculus?

Comment: This doesn't involve calculus at all! Work it out on paper and if you are stuck, tell me

Comment: Isn't trigonometry calculus?

Comment: I don't think so certainly, it can be said to be covered in precalculus, it definitely isn't calculus. In calculus, we deal with limits, continuity, derivatives and things like that. What is your background exactly? Do you know little bit of trigonometry? Further hint : Write $sin(A) + cos(A) $ as $\sqrt{2} ( 1/\sqrt{2} sin(A) + 1/\sqrt{2} cos(A))$ and use the formula for $sin(A+B)$, also it helps to know that maximum value of $sin$ or $cos$ is $1$.

Comment: Then what is the solution you are looking for? Otherwise plot graph.

Comment: I just solved it and checked back to tell you, but I saw your solution so I can confirm my answer. Thank you for the help @P-addict!! :)

Comment: @infinity Glad that you did it yourself, keep up the good work!